# Returning a value from a CallBack function in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have written a code for consumer in Spring Boot RabbitMQ. After getting the message, I want to further process it. But for that, I want access to it outside the callback. I have skipped some of the irrelevant code inside Postmapping function.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class PlottingRabbitMQ {
    private static Map<String, String> linkParams = new HashMap<>();
    static Logger logger
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginRabbitMQ.class);

private final static String PLOTTING_RESEND_QUEUE = "plotting_resend";

@JsonDeserialize
@PostMapping(value = "/plotting")
public Object createLink(@RequestBody PlottingModel plotting, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> plottingHeaders) throws Exception {
        
        ConnectionFactory factory_plotting_resend = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory_plotting_resend.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection_plotting_resend = factory_plotting_resend.newConnection();
        Channel channel_plotting_resend = connection_plotting_resend.createChannel();
        channel_plotting_resend.queueDeclare(PLOTTING_RESEND_QUEUE,
                false, false,false, null);
        logger.info("[!] Waiting for messages. To exit press Ctrl+C");


        Consumer consumer_plotting_resend = new DefaultConsumer(channel_plotting_resend){
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                       Envelope envelope,
                                       AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                       byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String respBodyPlotting = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                logger.info("[x] Message Received' " + respBodyPlotting + "'");
            }
        };
        
        channel_plotting_resend.basicConsume(PLOTTING_RESEND_QUEUE, true, consumer_plotting_resend);
        System.out.println("Received outside callback is: " + respBodyPlotting);
```

As you can see right at the bottom, I have written a system out where I want to print `respBodyPlotting` outside the channel_plotting_resend callback (I'm getting an error when I try to print it). In `logger.info`, I'm receiving the message but I'm clueless on how to getting it outside the function. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```java
final BlockingQueue<String> response = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel){
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                       Envelope envelope,
                                       AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                       byte[] body) throws IOException {
              response.offer(new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             }
        };
        
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE, true, consumer);
System.out.println("Received outside callback is: " + response.take());
```